# Glycation of peptides (Maillard reaction) by reductive amination

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, redox, biochemistry, amino-acids

I would like to link glucose to the primary amines in a peptide containing lysine. Can I just mix glucose and the peptide and add some cyanoborohydride to perform a reductive amination? As long as my peptides dont have any additional aldehydes it shouldnt polymerize, right?
Its difficult to get a confirmation that this will work from google because of the massive amount of literature on the in-vivo/in-pan reactions that takes place naturally

Comment: looks like you can  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2629553/